# trivial Picard group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

let $S=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be an affine scheme. For which ring $A$, not field is it known that $H^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S^{*})$ is trivial?

If $X\to S$ is a finite map and $H^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S^{*})$ is trivial, is it true that also $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^{*})$ is trivial?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sample answers to your first question: If $S$ is Spec of a local ring, or of a UFD, then $H^1(S, \mathcal O_S^{\times})$ is trivial.

The answer to your second question is *no*: $X = $Spec $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 +x) \to S =$ Spec $\mathbb C[x]$ gives a counterexample of a geometric nature, and $X =$Spec $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \to S =$ Spec $\mathbb Z$ gives a counterexample of an arithmetic nature.

Comment: is this true for coherent cohomology? Namely if $S$ is affine and $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent on $X$, $X\to S$ finite, is it true that $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $i>0$?

Comment: Yes, because $X$ is affine under your hypotheses!

Comment: @Matt E: can you explain how to compute $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ in your geometric example?

Comment: @adrido: Dear adrido, Recall that $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^{\times})$ is the Picard group of $X$.  In the geometric example, the curve $X$ is a once-punctured geometric curve, so its Pic is equal to Pic of an elliptic curve modulo the copy of $\mathbb Z$ generated by a single point (i.e. the point we punctured), which is naturally isomorphic to Pic${}^0$ of the elliptic curve.  But this is isomorphic to the elliptic curve itself.  In other words, in the geometric example, we have $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^{\times})$ is isomorphic to an elliptic curve.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Dear Matt, that's brilliant, thank you! so the projective curve defined by $wy^2-x^3+wx^2$ is elliptic and once you take out a point (w=0) you get the affine curve above. I wonder if you can  generalize this trick to compute the Picard group of affine varieties that are cones over a nice projective variety? e.g. V(xy-z^2)?

Comment: @adrido: Dear adrido, I think [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/73895/2874) might give an answer (or at least a partial answer) to your question.  Cheers,

Comment: @MattE: Dear Matt, this was indeed useful. Thank you!