# Naive Line Bundle Functor isn't a Zariski Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, algebraic-stacks

I'm reading a [set of notes on algebraic stacks](http://www.tolypreygel.com/notes/note_stacks.pdf) by Anatoly Preygel, and in the opening paragraphs it says

> Meanwhile *moduli problems*... often have the property that the functor
>
> $$T \mapsto \{ \text{isomorphism classes of ... over $T$} \}$$
>
> is not only not a scheme but not even a sheaf. Indeed taking ... to be "line bundles" shows that it is not even a Zariski sheaf: The stalks of the presheaf are all trivial, but there can exist non-trivial sections.

I think I know what this means, but I'm relying on two guesses (which I'm charitably calling "intuition" in my attempt below). If someone could please verify them, and provide any other insight you think might be valuable, I would really appreciate it!

---

Write $\mathsf{Aff}$ for the opposite of the category of finitely presented rings.

Let's call this functor $\mathcal{L} : \mathsf{Aff}^\text{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$, so it's a presheaf on $\mathsf{Aff}$. We want to show that it's *not* a sheaf for the (big) Zariski topology. We'll do that by showing that

1. each stalk is trivial
2. there are nontrivial sections

After all, if each stalk is trivial, then by uniqueness of gluing for sheaves, we should only get trivial sections. So if (1) and (2) are both satisfied, we'll show that $\mathcal{L}$ isn't a sheaf.

Let's start with (2), which is easier. A section of $\mathcal{L}$ is just $\mathcal{L}(\text{Spec} S)$ for your favorite (finitely presented) ring $S$. Of course, there are plenty of rings admitting nontrivial line bundles (said another way, there are plenty of rings $S$ with nontrivial picard group) so that nontrivial sections of $\mathcal{L}$ are abundant.

Next up is (1). According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310512/points-of-the-big-zariski-site) MO question, points of $\mathcal{E} = \mathsf{Sh}(\mathsf{Aff}, \text{Zar})$ are local rings $R$. Indeed, the inverse image part of the point (read: geometric morphism) $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathcal{E}$ will be given by $R^* : \mathcal{E} \to \mathsf{Set}$, the kan extension of $\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}(R),-) : \mathsf{Aff} \to \mathsf{Set}$ along the (yoneda) embedding $y : \mathsf{Aff} \to \mathcal{E}$. The good news is that we only need to understand $R^*$, since the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at $R$ is exactly $R^* \mathcal{L}$. The bad news is that I'm inexperienced with making these calculations...

Intuition says that $R$ is a colimit of its finitely presented subrings, each of which is an object of $\mathsf{Aff}$. So each finitely presented subring is like an "open set containing $R$", and we should be able to compute the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at $R$ as $\text{colim } \mathcal{L}(\text{Spec} R_i)$, where the $R_i$ are the finitely presented subrings of $R$... Much weaker intuition says that this should be the same thing as invertible sheaves on $R$. This gives the expected answer since [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167450/trivial-picard-group) the picard group for local rings is trivial (remember $R$ was local).

So indeed, if the above is correct, each stalk is trivial, showing (1), and we're done.

---

Thanks in advance for any thoughts! ^_^

Comment: Your reasoning is not quite correct since you do not know that your presheaf $L$ preserves (filtered) colimits. Instead you have make a slightly more sophisticated argument: for any line bundle and any point you can find a neighbourhood of that point on which the line bundle is trivial.

Comment: @ZhenLin would you mind elaborating? Your comment looks like it might be referring to the little zariski topos, but maybe that's just showing the flexibility of the language. Here, as I understand it, a point is a local ring $R$ and a neighborhood is one of its finitely presented subrings, right? So, in simpler language, would the "more sophisticated argument" be something like "for each fp ring $R_0$ and each line bundle $L$ on $\text{Spec}(R_0)$, for each local ring $R \supseteq R_0$, there's an fp ring $R_0 \subseteq R_1 \subseteq R$ so that $L \restriction_{\text{Spec}(R_1)}$ is trivial"?

Comment: Actually, even writing that down was helpful... That really does look like it's related to something like a stalk in the "small" case, which partially answers a question I left in a comment on David's answer.

Comment: If you have a sheaf on the big Zariski site then (omitting details slightly) it restricts to a sheaf on the small Zariski site of every scheme (that is an object in the big site). The converse is also true, if you are careful about how to interpret these words.

Comment: @ZhenLin, do you have a reference for that? Maybe somewhere in Mac Lane and Moerdijk or similar?

Comment: I do not have a reference. It's easy anyway: a sieve in the big Zariski site covers if and only if it contains a set of monomorphisms corresponding to an open cover of the codomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first idea is correct, that the stalk can be computed as a colimit
$$\mathrm{colim}\, \mathcal{L}(R_i)$$
where the $R_i$ are the finitely presented subrings of $R$.

The reason is as follows. The category of points of a presheaf topos $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ agrees with the opposite of the category of pro-objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Equivalently, it agrees with the category of ind-objects in $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$. An ind-object is written formally as $\varinjlim_i R_i$ for $(R_i)_i$ a filtered diagram in $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$. The stalk of a presheaf $F$ at a point $\varinjlim_i R_i$ is given by $\varinjlim F(R_i)$. (I write $\varinjlim$ rather than $\mathrm{colim}$ to emphasize that the colimit is filtered.)

Now if there is a Grothendieck topology $J$ on $\mathcal{C}$, then a point $\varinjlim R_i$ of $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ factors through the sheaf topos $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C},J)$ if and only if the point is "$J$-local" in some sense. See for example Gabber–Kelly, ["Points in algebraic geometry"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5782v2), Section 1. The stalk of a sheaf $F$ at a point $\varinjlim R_i$ is still given by $\varinjlim F(R_i)$.

In the case of the big Zariski topos, $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ is the category of finitely presented rings. The ind-category of the category of finitely presented rings is the category of all rings, with the formal symbol $\varinjlim_i R_i$ in the ind-category corresponding to the actual colimit $\varinjlim_i R_i$ in the category of rings. A ring is $J$-local, with $J$ the Zariski topology, if and only if it is a local ring. A ring $R$ can be written as a filtered colimit of its finitely presented subrings $R_i$, and then the stalk of your sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ is given by $\varinjlim \mathcal{L}(R_i)$.

To show that the stalk is trivial, take some finitely presented subring $S$ of $R$, and let $L$ be a line bundle on $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$. Take an element $f \in S$ such that $L$ is trivial on $\mathrm{Spec}(S_f)$ and such that the map $\mathrm{Spec}(R) \to \mathrm{Spec}(S)$
factorizes through $\mathrm{Spec}(S_f)$. Then $f$ is invertible in $R$, so $S_f$ is a (finitely presented) subring of $R$. We conclude that the line bundle $L$ becomes trivial after base change to some larger finitely presented subring. This shows that the colimit $\varinjlim \mathcal{L}(R_i)$ is trivial.

Your second idea avoids the last part of the above proof by using instead the fact that the Picard group of a local ring is trivial. This also works, but it relies on more technical machinery. You can compute:
$$\varinjlim \mathcal{L}(R_i) \simeq \varinjlim \mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Spec}(R_i), \mathbb{G}_{m,R_i})
\simeq \mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Spec}(R), \mathbb{G}_{m,R}) \simeq \mathrm{Pic}(R) \simeq 0.$$
The first and third isomorphism are based on the cohomological formulation of the Picard group. I didn't specify on which site the cohomology groups are computed (big or small, Zariski or étale) because in this case it doesn't matter. The second isomorphism uses SGA4, Exposé VII, Théorème 5.7 and the fact that $\varinjlim \phi_i^*\mathbb{G}_{m,R_i} \simeq \mathbb{G}_{m,R}$, for $\phi_i : \mathrm{Spec}(R) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R_i)$ the natural map. See also the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/344390/).

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you so much ^_^. I like to leave my questions open for a week or so to give as many people a chance to chime in as possible, but I'll almost certainly accept this in a few days. As a quick followup, your website says that you're interested in the application of topos theory to concrete problems. I'm _also_ interested in this, but it's hard to find examples of honest calculations like the ones in your answer. Would you mind sharing some books or papers you found helpful in learning this? I can also send you an email (which has more space than a comment on mse, haha)

Comment: Ok, let’s discuss further by e-mail! In case other people are interested: I learned about computing points of toposes by trying to understand some of the work by Connes and Consani. Their [arithmetic site](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4527) has as underlying topos the category of presheaves on a category with one objects and as morphisms the natural numbers under multiplication. They found a very elegant description of the points of this topos in terms of finite adeles. An alternative way of looking at the points was given by my PhD advisor [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01627).

Comment: I was interested in how their computations would work for other monoids and the paper by Gabber and Kelly above was extremely helpful. Their explanation is based on SGA4, but they also show immediately how it works in practice. It helped to go through the strategy explained by Gabber–Kelly in the particular case of the Arithmetic Site. I already knew what the end result would have to be, thanks to Connes and Consani.

Even the very concrete description of Gabber–Kelly is not always enough in practice… for example, it is an open problem to determine the points for the flat topology.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\Pic{\text{Pic}}$You are writing things in a very sophisticated way. I'm going to respond to the question at the top but not try to follow all of the thoughts in the middle. For a scheme $X$, I'll write $\Pic(X)$ for the abelian group of isomorphisms classes of line bundles on $X$.

(1) The functor $U \mapsto \Pic(U)$ is not a sheaf.

The "locality" condition in the [definition of a sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Sheaves) says that, if $X = U \cup V$ is an open cover, and $A$ and $B$ are line bundles on $X$ with $A|_U \cong B|_U$ and $A|_V \cong B|_V$, then $A \cong B$. This is the opposite of how line bundles work!

Take $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and let $U$ and $V$ be the standard cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ by two $\mathbb{A}^1$'s. Every line bundle becomes trivial on $U$ and on $V$, but $\mathbb{P}^1$ has nontrivial line bundles.

If you for want $X$ to be affine as well (since your original question talked about $\text{Aff}$) take $X = \text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $U = \text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}, 2^{-1}]$ and $V =  \text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}, 3^{-1}]$. Again, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD but $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}, 2^{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}, 3^{-1}]$ are, so there are nontrivial line bundles on $X$ which become trivial on each of $U$ and $V$.

(2) The stronger statement that the stalks of $U \mapsto \Pic(U)$ are all trivial. I find the language of stalks on the big Zariski site awkward, so let's just talk about open sets on a fixed scheme $X$. Then $U \mapsto \Pic(U)$ is a presheaf on $X$.

Let $p$ be any point of $X$. Then the stalk of this presheaf is $\lim_{\to} \Pic(V)$ where the limit is over all open neighborhoods $V$ of $p$. Let $U$ be any open neighborhood of $p$, and let $L$ be any line bundle on $U$. Then there is some neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $L|_V$ is trivial (that's what a line bundle means!). So $[L]$ maps to $1$ in $\Pic(V)$. So every class becomes trivial in the stalk.

Comment: This was helpful (+1), even if not exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the more concrete way of seeing that our functor isn't a sheaf (I prefer to be concrete when possible) but the question was mainly about how to understand the statement about stalks in the big zariski topos (since I also found them awkward to think about). I would be happier with the second part of your answer if there were a way (either precise or intuitively) in which trivialitly of the "small" stalks (which I agree is obvious!) should be related to triviality of the "big" stalks.

Comment: This morning I thought I vaguely knew what a point of the big Zariski site meant but, now that I have read https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05UZ , I do not think I understand it at all. I'll have to leave this to someone else.

Comment: No worries at all! Thanks again for all the help that's already in your answer ^_^